# Fusioncharts does not diplay on mobile devices

Tags: php, javascript, xml, fusioncharts

I have problem with fusioncharts, I use PHP and JavaScript.
Here are code:

```
<div id="chartdiv_krpb" class="chartdiv_krpb"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart;
    myChart = new FusionCharts("swf/Pie2D.swf", "myChart_krpb", "100%", "240", "0", "1");
    myChart.setDataURL("data/krpb.php?thnang=<? echo $thnang; ?>");
    myChart.render("chartdiv_krpb");
</script>
```

krpb.php

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT acronym AS 'KODE', SUM(RPHREAL) AS RPHREAL FROM t_sai LEFT JOIN rosi_chat.t_perk2 ON kdperk2 = LEFT(PERKSAI, 2) WHERE THNANG = '$thnang' AND RPHREAL > 0 AND t_perk2.kdtrn = '3' AND kdkem = '0' AND kdperk2 IN ('51','52', '53', '57') GROUP BY kdperk2") or die(mysql_error());

$strXML = "<chart pieRadius='90' showPercentageValues='1' showValues='1' numberScaleValue='1000,1000,1000,1000' numberScaleUnit=' K, J, M, T' formatNumberScale='1' animation='0' numdivlines='3' baseFontSize='9' baseFontColor='000000'  showBorder='0'  caption='Realization' bgColor='7A864E' bgAlpha='50,75' bgRatio='75' bgAngle='270' canvasBgColor='A7AB50' canvasBgAlpha='50,75' canvasBgRatio='75' canvasBgAngle='270' canvasBorderThickness='0'>";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $strData .= "<set label='" . $record['CODE'] . "' value='" . $record['RPHREAL'] . "' />";
}
$strXML .=  $strData . "</chart>";
echo $strXML;
```

Problem is fusioncharts on iOS, Android and other mobile devices can't load chart?

Comment: It appears you are using flash based charts?

Comment: "Loading chart, please wait" only, thanks for quick reply

Comment: Flash is no longer supported on mobile devices. You should force the javascript renderer to ensure that its not trying to load flash. You can sort of access developer tools on a mobile device in safari or chrome. May take some setup however.

Comment: The HTML5 Charting charting files such as `FusionCharts.HC.js` and `FusionCharts.HC.charts.js` should reside on your server right beside `FusionCharts.js`

Comment: Before I'm not use FusionCharts.HC.js and others result not show anything, after I put in, "Loading chart, please wait" only.

Comment: To render chart in iOS and other mobile device, please ensure FusionCharts.js, FusionCharts.HC.js, FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js and jquery.min.js are present within the same folder.

Comment: Yes, all files in same folder (js folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be perfect and your problem can be because of one of the following-

1) Some of the .js files are missing or not in the same folder.

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/Introduction/DownloadC.html

2) The path provided is wrong.

3) iPhone, iPad, iTouch, Android(>Honeycomb) etc. use flash- check out the documentation for explicit rendering in JavaScript mode.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/getting-started/your-first-charts/building-your-first-chart.html can be used for reference.

Comment: Thank for answered, currently I put .js file at js folder, .swf at swf folder.

Comment: now, is succeeded. I put .js file and .swf file in the same folder (FusionCharts), and "tara" ..... chart showing automatically.